# Which is the better way to write a conditional statement?

Tags: conditional-content

Which is better...

```
<?php if (is_page()): ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (is_page()) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no performance difference. And both styles are acceptable by [WordPress Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#brace-style) as you can read in:

> Braces should always be used, even when they are not required:

and

> Note that requiring the use of braces just means that single-statement
>   inline control structures are prohibited. You are free to use the
>   alternative syntax for control structures (e.g. if/endif,
>   while/endwhile)—especially in your templates where PHP code is
>   embedded within HTML

I always use the brace styles beucause I think is more widely known by PHP programmers of different levels and makes the block "hierarchy" much clearer and easier to understand.

Bottom line: you should choose what is more convenient to you. And whichever you choose, be consistent and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know which is better. Exploring the different conditional statements syntax.

I believe they are all just **alternative syntax** and have no real performance difference.
**You can have:**

```
<?php if (is_page()): ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**OR:**

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**also ternary operator:**

```
<?php echo is_page() ? "Is page" : "Not a page"; ?>
```

Comment: thanks! i was looking for the ternary operator